# Calculate time of received 802.11 packets

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, relational-database, data-modeling

I have a router that's sniffing packets and stores the device id, the signal strength and the time stamp in a MySQL database. These are all stored in one table, with the fields: device_id, signal_strength and time_stamp. Each record represents one received packet. 
Since I receive packets from multiple sources the records in the database are in a random order.

I want to calculate the time from the first packet per mac address until the last packet I have received. So I won't to know how long a device is measured. This is were I'm stuck. I don't know how to calculate or query this. Maybe my database design isn't optimal?

EDIT: example data

```
record_id   device_id   date        time    signal_strength 
 32         2           2014-02-20  10:52:52    -9  
 33         2           2014-02-20  10:52:52    -14 
 34         2           2014-02-20  10:52:53    -9  
 35         2           2014-02-20  10:52:53    -10 
 36         2           2014-02-20  10:52:53    -10 
 37         7           2014-02-20  10:52:53    -53 
 38         2           2014-02-20  10:52:53    -15 
 39         2           2014-02-20  10:52:53    -9  
 40         2           2014-02-20  10:52:53    -9  
 41         2           2014-02-20  10:52:53    -10 
 42         2           2014-02-20  10:52:54    -13 
 43         2           2014-02-20  10:52:54    -9  
 44         7           2014-02-20  10:52:54    -60 
 45         2           2014-02-20  10:52:54    -10 
 46         2           2014-02-20  10:52:54    -9  
 47         2           2014-02-20  10:52:54    -9  
 48         2           2014-02-20  10:52:54    -10 
 49         2           2014-02-20  10:52:55    -13 
 50         7           2014-02-20  10:52:55    -56 
 51         2           2014-02-20  10:52:55    -15 
 52         7           2014-02-20  10:52:55    -58 
 53         2           2014-02-20  10:52:55    -26 
 54         2           2014-02-20  10:52:55    -14 
 55         2           2014-02-20  10:52:56    -13 
 56         2           2014-02-20  10:52:56    -12 
 57         2           2014-02-20  10:52:56    -9  
 58         2           2014-02-20  10:52:56    -11
 59         2           2014-02-20  10:52:56    -13 
 60         7           2014-02-20  10:52:56    -55 
 61         2           2014-02-20  10:52:57    -14
```

I'm trying to ORDER BY `device_id` AND `time` but I don't know how to ask for the last time per device.  Also a device can be measured more than once per day. In other words devices can enter the sniffing field more than once. So I need to distinguish if it's the first time entered within the field or a second time.

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide some data example? I guess you could count in SQL time between Max(time_stamp) and Min(time_stamp) per MAC address, but there is the problem if you can't differ the packets by some field or value or anything ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with to get Start and End time you can use `MIN` and `MAX` like so

```
SELECT Device_id
,MIN(concat(date,' ',time)) as StartTime
,MAX(concat(date,' ',time)) as EndTime
,MIN(TIMESTAMP(date,time)) as StartTime2
,MAX(TIMESTAMP(date,time)) as EndTime2
From MyTable
Group by Device_ID
```

than all you need is to calculate the difference between Start and End time. For that you can use `TIMEDIFF` function. Full documentation on all these functions http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestamp